# need to debug a dependency locally

Tags: go

I need to debug a project with a few prints to stdout: https://github.com/protolambda/zcli

and it has a dependency on this: https://github.com/protolambda/zrnt

The piece of code I need to debug is inside of `zrnt`.

I've installed the `zcli` tool locally with `go get -u -tags preset_minimal github.com/protolambda/zcli` and I can see the code for `zrnt` in both `~/go/pkg/mod/github.com` and `~/go/src/github.com` - so my question is: Where should I edit and what command should I use to rebuild it?

And is there any easy way of removing all local changes from a package's source when I'm done - something like `git checkout .`?

I'm totally new to Go and it would be desirable if I could avoid learning about the package management for a few hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this, use [Go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).

1. Menually active module mode:

```
$ export GO111MODULE=on
```

2. Initialize a new module:

```
$ go mod init github.com/protolambda/zcli

go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/protolambda/zcli
```

3. Now go to the project directory (`$cd github.com/protolambda/zcli`) and run:

```
$ go mod tidy
$ go mod vendor
```

4. Running those commands will create a `vendor` folder with all the dependencies. Edit them the way you like & use the following command to build your project.

```
$ go build ./...
```

5. Use `$ go mod vendor` to reset the main module's vendor directory.